# List 1 to 20 file names with pattern in UNIX

Tags: shell, unix

I have following command in UNIX Shell to list files from current directory with suffix pattern 1 to 9

```
ls cat[1-9]
```

Output
**cat1 cat2 cat3 cat4 cat5 cat6 cat7 cat8 cat9**

But When I try to use following command i get unexpected result

```
ls cat[1-10]
```

Output
**cat1**

instead i should get cat1 to cat10 all files

Comment: `[1-9]` is a range of characters, not numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `list glob`:

```
ls cat{1..9}
```

To exclude `cat7`:

Use:

```
ls cat{{1..6},{8,9}}
```

OR else:

```
ls cat[^7]
```

Comment: And What if i want to exclude file cat7 from this list

Comment: Sorry couldn't understand the requirement.

Comment: `ls cat{{1..6},{8..10}}`

Comment: @Graeme: Thanks so much, hsaka: Is this you're looking for?

Comment: yes thanks a lot, previously someone told me to use ls cat[1-6,8-10] but it wasnt giving me exact output. thank you @Graeme

Comment: Close, but `[]` is lexical, ie you can do `[a-z]` but not `[1-10]`. `{..}` is numerical and `{,}` is a list.

Comment: @Graeme: Yes totally agree, so `cat[^7]` can in theory match `catX`

Answer (score 0):

Your glob expression matches a list of characters, not numbers. `cat[1-10]` will match files named 'cat1' (cat1 through cat1) and 'cat0', and that's it. You could use a brace expansion, `cat{1..10}`, but that will expand whether or not such files actually exist, so you could end up with file not found errors later on in your script. The only way to be sure is to filter the list directly:

```
cats=()
for cat in cat[0-9]*; do
  if [[ ${cat#cat} ^= *[^0-9]* ]]; then # if the part after "cat" is numeric
    cats+=("$cat")
  fi
done
```